# Django can't run in Hostmonster

Tags: django, fastcgi, hostmonster

I had setup a simple Django project in hostmonster:
The project name is thep_viet, the app is mainapp
my .htaccess is

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

my django.fcgi is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- mode: python; -*-

import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/riasolut/django/django_projects/")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
#os.chdir("/home/riasolut/django/django_projects/thep_viet")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "thep_viet.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

I'm setting python 2.7.2 and django 1.3.1 succesfully

I'm create a folder named thep_viet in ~/django/django_projects/. This folder contain all source code of thep_viet project.

I'm create a folder named thep_viet in public_html and place .htaccess and django.fcgi in this.
When I'm running django.fcgi by command line:

```
python ~/public_html/thep_viet/django.fcgi
```

I receive the result:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE"><title>Welcome to Django</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; }
    h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
    h2 span { font-size:80%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
    h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
    table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
    tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    thead th { padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ddd; }
    tbody th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    ul { margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 1em; }
    #summary { background: #e0ebff; }
    #summary h2 { font-weight: normal; color: #666; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; }
    #instructions { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #summary table { border:none; background:transparent; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>It worked!</h1>
  <h2>Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.</h2>
</div>

<div id="instructions">
  <p>Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Here's what to do next:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>If you plan to use a database, edit the <code>DATABASES</code> setting in <code>thep_viet/settings.py</code>.</li>
    <li>Start your first app by running <code>python thep_viet/manage.py startapp [appname]</code>.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p>
    You're seeing this message because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in your
    Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!
  </p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

It seem django can run effectly

But when I'm running in browser:

```
thepviet.mydomain.com
```

with thepviet.mydomain.com point to mydomain.com/thep_viet

I receive the 500 error:

```
<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

Did I forget any thing? I thing something wrong in config fastcgi in apache of hostmonster.

Please help my problem.

---

I've read the error log and found:

```
[Fri Nov 18 19:50:04 2011] [warn] [client 113.185.2.152] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Nov 18 19:50:04 2011] [error] [client 113.185.2.152] Premature end of script headers: django.fcgi
[Fri Nov 18 19:50:04 2011] [error] [client 113.185.2.152] invalid CGI ref "/500.php" in /home4/riasolut/public_html/500.shtml
```

Is this error belong to the FastCGI server or my code?

Comment: There is likely to be an entry in the error log file.  That would more than likely help find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `fcgi` file:

```
runfastcgi(method="threaded", "daemonize="false")
```

The quote mark before `daemonize` shouldn't be there.

As Jack M says in the comment, if you'd looked in the server error log, you would almost certainly see the error there.

Comment: I've fix the quote befor daemonize, that is simple my edit error when post. I read the error log and see that error: